# compile with different opencv

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to compile a ros package skimap_ros with a local version on opencv. All my attempts at overriding the libraries in the CMakeLists.txt have failed ...it keeps taking the opencv from /usr.  Does anyone know how to do this in ROS. Thank you\

getting erros of the form:

> /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:143:47:
> error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before
> ‘<’ token
> void computeImpl( const Mat& image, vector& keypoints,
> Mat& descriptors ) const;

path is wrong should be /home/rjn/opencv-2.4.13.3/install/

have  tried specifying on catkin build line

> -DOpenCV_DIR="-L/home/rjn/opencv-2.4.13.3/install/lib
> -I/home/rjn/opencv-2.4.13.3/install/include"

and

> -DCPPFLAGS="-L/path/to/opencv2.4.9/lib -I/path/to/opencv2.4.9/include"

and
overriding directly in CMakeLists

The directory: exist

> /home/rjn/opencv-2.4.13.3/install/include/opencv2/nonfree

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272390/compile-with-different-opencv/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be nice if you can share what have you tried but this is how I would do it:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED
   NO_MODULE #Should be optional, tells CMake to use config mode
   PATHS /usr/local # Tells CMake to look here
   NO_DEFAULT_PATH #and don't look anywhere else
)
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2017-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2020-06-13**:
Hello, I have two opencv folder under /usr/local which is opencv and opencv2. If I want to use opencv2 as the include library, then I should specific **/usr/local/opencv2** in the **PATHS** option? Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2020-06-14**:
You can add next OpenCV the version you want to work with, for eg. find_package(OpenCV 4.01 REQUIRED ...